# Javascript condition dilemma

Tags: javascript

thanks for reading, I have a problem with part of my code, the code is the following (for better access I included the css and js all in the html):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Comparacion 3 numeros.</title>
    <style media="screen">
      body{
      background: #1b2539;
      color: #869443;
      text-align: center;

      }

      #box1{
        width: 300px;
        background:#2ba15a;
        color:#751434;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 28px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin-top: 50px;
      }

      div {
        margin: auto;
      }

      div p {
        font-size: 32px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #25e421;
        margin-top: 15%;
        display: inline-block;

      }
      form{
        display: inline-block;
        align-content: center;
        margin-top: 50px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function show(){

        var a,b,c,heaviest;

        a=parseFloat(document.getElementById('b1').value);
        b=parseFloat(document.getElementById('b2').value);
        c=parseFloat(document.getElementById('b3').value);
        d=parseFloat(document.getElementById('b4').value);



        if(a==b){
         if(c<d){
            heaviest=d;
         }else{
         heaviest=c;
        }

        }else{
        if(a<b){
        heaviest=b;
        }else{
        heaviest=a;
        }
        }


        if (( (a>b&&c&&d) && (b==c==d) ) || ( (b>a&&c&&d) && (a==c==d) ) || ( (c>a&&b&&d) && (a==b==d) ) || ( (d>a&&b&&c) && (a==b==c) )){
           document.getElementById('box1').innerHTML = "Heaviest is: " + heaviest + ".<br />";
        }
        else{
           document.getElementById('box1').innerHTML = "Try again.<br />";
        }

      }

    </script>

    <form action="" onsubmit="show(); return false">

      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter first ball" id="b1"><br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter second ball" id="b2"><br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter third ball" id="b3"><br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter fourth ball" id="b4"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Heaviest" onclick="show()">

    </form>

    <div id="box1">
        <br>
    </div>

    <div>
      <p>Enter 3 equal weights and 1 heavier!</p>
    </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

What I want you to focus is on this part:

```
        if (( (a>b&&c&&d) && (b==c==d) ) || ( (b>a&&c&&d) && (a==c==d) ) || ( (c>a&&b&&d) && (a==b==d) ) || ( (d>a&&b&&c) && (a==b==c) )){
           document.getElementById('box1').innerHTML = "Heaviest is: " + heaviest + ".<br />";
        }
        else{
           document.getElementById('box1').innerHTML = "Try again.<br />";
        }
```

What I tried to do here is check if there are 3 equal inputs (doesn't matter in which order) and another input bigger than the other 3, if so, then call show(); if not, display try again, I know that certainly there's a better way to do all this, but I'm learning and first want to do it the way I know, and to me that part is ok, so i don't get why it is not working. I appreciate any correction.

Comment: `a>b&&c&&d` is equivalent to `(a>b) && (c) && (d)`, what you want is `(a>b) && (a>c) && (a>d)`. 

`b==c==d` is invalid, what you want is `b==c && c==d`


Oh and if `b==c==d` then just do one gt comparison (since they are equal) like `a>b && (b==c && ==d)`

Comment: only a pointer.. `if` statement. what do you expect a>b&&c&&d to return ? If your intention is _`a` should be greater than `b`,`c` and `d`_ then this is not the correct way to represent it. Same goes for the other clause in the`if`

Comment: thanks @vivick that worked and now I get it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this code:

```js
var a = b = c = '20', d = '120';
var arr = [a,b,c,d].sort((a,b) => a - b);

//Option 1
if(arr[0] == arr[1] && arr[1] == arr[2] && arr[2] * 1 < arr[3] * 1){
  //Do something
}

//Option 2 (for more than 3 elements)
var i = 0;
while(arr[i++] == arr[i] && i < arr.length - 1);
if(i == arr.length - 1  && arr[i] * 1 > arr[i - 1] * 1){
  //Do something
}
```

Comment: Using static indices in arrays does not scale well

Comment: He didn't ask for a scaling solution, but if needed I added a code for that.

Comment: @Tal, you need to use a sorting function or it will compare strings and sort like `[1, 11, 2]` because `"11" < "2"`. And you can do the whole thing (with scaling and stuff) as `var arr = [a,b,c,d].sort((a,b) => a-b), heaviest = arr.pop();
if(arr.every(value => value === arr[0] && value < heaviest)){ /*...*/ }`

Comment: But bruno code using float, not strings.
Anyhow, the sorting function is a nice addition for numbers that stored as strings.

Comment: I already do that I think, 

          a=parseFloat(document.getElementById('b1').value);
          b=parseFloat(document.getElementById('b2').value);
          c=parseFloat(document.getElementById('b3').value);
          d=parseFloat(document.getElementById('b4').value);

isn't that sufficient?

Comment: It's sufficient, you could also use: `document.getElementById('b3').value * 1` to get the same result :)

Comment: @Tal im facing a problem, it works for negative numbers to 9 only

Comment: What works for negative numbers to 9 only? the sorting works with every number unless they are strings. if so, add @Thomas sorting function to the solution.

Comment: @Tal, Array#sort() sorts everything as Strings, unless you explicitely tell it to do different. check this out: `[-11,-33,-55, -1,-3,-5, 1,3,5, 11,33,55].sort()` and the negative numbers only come first because the charCode of `-` is < than the charCode of `0`. And the `*1` part in `(a,b) => a*1 - b*1` is redundant because due to the subtraction, JS already has to convert `a` and `b` into Numbers

Comment: I didn't knew that, Thank you for your comment.

Comment: what's the purpose if the `* 1`?

Comment: in this case it's not necessary since the number converted to floats. but for more generic case were they could be strings, we need to convert the last 2 elements to number.
lets take the case above: a = b = c = 20, d = 120. the sorted array will be: '20', '20', '20', '120'. now arr[2] > arr[3] as strings but arr[2] < arr[3] as numbers.
arr[i-1] * 1 make sure that the comparison is between numbers.